# Android Room Insert not inserting and doing nothing

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-hilt

I'm new to android and room. I'm using Dagger Hilt to inject the Database but when I'm using Insert method nothing happen.

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_table")
@Parcelize
data class Product(

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id : String,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title : String,
    @SerializedName("price")
    val price : String,
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category : String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description : String,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image : String,

    val color : String,
    val size : String
): Parcelable
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface CartDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
    fun get_all_carts(): LiveData<List<Product>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert_item_to_cart(product: Product) : Long

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete_item_from_cart(product: Product)


    @Query("Delete FROM product_table")
    fun delete_all_cart()

}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Product::class], version = 1)
abstract class ProductDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun productDao(): CartDao
}
```

Dagger Hilt Modult:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MainActivityModule {

    // Retrofit code

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(
        app: Application,
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        app,
        ProductDatabase::class.java,
        "product_db").build()

    @Provides
    fun provideTaskDao(db: ProductDatabase) = db.productDao()


}
```

Fragment View Model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productDao : CartDao
) : ViewModel() {

    init {

    }


    fun insert_item_to_cart(product: Product){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            productDao.insert_item_to_cart(product)
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment Button OnClickListener:

```
btn_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {

                val num = viewModel.insert_item_to_cart(
                    args.productData.copy(
                        color = selected_color,
                        size = selected_size
                    )
                )
                Log.d(TAG, "Inserted : ${num}")

            }
        })
```

As my Insert function returns `Long` which will be the primary key of the inserted product, this log should return that number but it's returning nothing at all. Hope someone can help me and thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `insert_item_to_cart` is being called?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm having some navigation stuff in the ```insert_item_to_cart``` all works fine. @HenryTwist

Comment: Oh, I've just seen you've printed the return of `insert_item_to_cart` but it has no return type? So it defintiely shouldn't print the number you're expecting. You can check on Android Studio whether the data has actually been inserted with the database inspector.

Comment: Oh, I checked it and actually it found no database connected. So the problem now in my dagger hilt module? @HenryTwist

Comment: Well if you're not getting a crash or compiler error then it's obviously getting injected fine so it seems unlikely. Have you tried logging the return value from your insert query?

Comment: Yes, as in the code above. It returns nothing. @HenryTwist

Comment: Well it must print something? Otherwise the method isn't being called?

Comment: I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on the line `productDao.insert_item_to_cart(product)` and  checking the relevant values whilst stepping through in debug mode. e.g. has `productDao` been correctly instantiated (no evidence that it has been in your code).

Comment: I dunno wherr was the problem. But I initialized the database manually without dagger hilt and now it's working. So just I'm not sure what was it.

Comment: But now my ```get_all_carts()``` crashes the app which sucks ffs.